# Mongoose - lean() returning bson data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bson

This query is not working as expecteed:

```
Model.find().select('_id').lean().exec(function(err, ids) {
    (...)
})
```

as far as I know lean() method should return the results of the query as js object., not mongodb bson.

**edit:**

actual result:

```
forEach(function(item, index, array) {
    console.log(item);
}
```

this:

```
_bsontype=ObjectID, 0=88, 1=198, 2=150, 3=109, 4=7, 5=81, 6=146, 7=44, 8=18, 9=94, 10=112, 11=159
_bsontype=ObjectID, 0=88, 1=198, 2=184, 3=185, 4=19, 5=120, 6=81, 7=12, 8=197, 9=73, 10=143, 11=217
_bsontype=ObjectID, 0=88, 1=198, 2=187, 3=53, 4=144, 5=27, 6=216, 7=20, 8=202, 9=80, 10=181, 11=183
_bsontype=ObjectID, 0=88, 1=198, 2=189, 3=10, 4=61, 5=115, 6=116, 7=28, 8=202, 9=233, 10=198, 11=106
```

expected results:

```
[{_id: "myid1"}, {_id: "myid2"}, {_id: "myid3"}, {_id: "myid4"}]
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect it to return and what does it return now? What's the output of `console.log(ids)`?

Comment: @JJJ edited with actual results and expected ones.

Comment: `.lean()` doesn't convert ObjectIDs into strings; it just returns a plain object instead of a Mongoose object. If you want strings instead of ObjectIDs, `ids = ids.map(function(item) { return { _id: item._id.toString() }});`

Comment: @JJJ lthanks man It worked. but when I used lean() with no select statement it returned string ids for every model ref. I know there's no objectId type on js.