# NodeJS MongoDB Mongoose export nested subdocuments and arrays to XLSX columns

Tags: node.js, excel, mongodb, xlsx

I have query results from MongoDB as an array of documents with nested subdocuments and arrays of subdocuments.

```
[
  {
    RecordID: 9000,
    RecordType: 'Item',
    Location: {
      _id: 5d0699326e310a6fde926a08,
      LocationName: 'Example Location A'
    }
    Items: [
      {
        Title: 'Example Title A',
        Format: {
          _id: 5d0699326e310a6fde926a01,
          FormatName: 'Example Format A'
        }
      },
      {
        Title: 'Example Title B',
        Format: {
          _id: 5d0699326e310a6fde926a01,
          FormatName: 'Example Format B'
        }
      }
    ],
  },
  {
    RecordID: 9001,
    RecordType: 'Item',
    Location: {
      _id: 5d0699326e310a6fde926a08,
      LocationName: 'Example Location C'
    },
    Items: [
      {
        Title: 'Example Title C',
        Format: {
          _id: 5d0699326e310a6fde926a01,
          FormatName: 'Example Format C'
        }
      }
    ],
  }
]
```

**Problem**

I need to export the results to XLSX in column order. The XLSX library is working to export the *top-level* properties (such as RecordID and RecordType) only. I also need to export the nested objects and arrays of objects. Given a list of property names e.g. `RecordID, RecordType, Location.LocationName, Items.Title, Items.Format.FormatName` the properties must be exported to XLSX columns in the specified order.

**Desired result**

Here is the desired 'flattened' structure (or something similar) that 
I think *should* be able to convert to XLSX columns.

```
[
  {
    'RecordID': 9000,
    'RecordType': 'Item',
    'Location.LocationName': 'Example Location A',
    'Items.Title': 'Example Title A, Example Title B',
    'Items.Format.FormatName': 'Example Format A, Example Format B',
  },
  {
    'RecordID': 9001,
    'RecordType': 'Item',
    'Location.LocationName': 'Example Location C',
    'Items.Title': 'Example Title C',
    'Items.Format.FormatName': 'Example Format C',
  }
]
```

I am using the XLSX library to convert the query results to XLSX which works for top-level properties only.

```
  const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(results.data);
  const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { 'data': worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
  const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });

  const data: Blob = new Blob([excelBuffer], { type: EXCEL_TYPE });
  FileSaver.saveAs(data, new Date().getTime());
```

**POSSIBLE OPTIONS**

I am guessing I need to 'flatten' the structure either using aggregation in the query or by performing post-processing when the query is returned.

**Option 1: Build the logic in the MongoDB query to flatten the results.**

[$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) might work since it is able to "promote an existing embedded document to the top level". Although I am not sure if this will solve the problem exactly, I do not want to modify the documents in place, I just need to flatten the results for exporting.

Here is the MongoDB query I am using to produce the results:

```
records.find({ '$and': [ { RecordID: { '$gt': 9000 } } ]},
  { skip: 0, limit: 10, projection: { RecordID: 1, RecordType: 1, 'Items.Title': 1, 'Items.Location': 1 }});
```

**Option 2: Iterate and flatten the results on the Node server**

This is likely not the most performant option, but might be the easiest if I can't find a way to do so within the MongoDB query.

**UPDATE:**

I may be able to use MongoDB aggregate `$project` to 'flatten' the results. For example, this aggregate query effectively 'flattens' the results by 'renaming' the properties. I just need to figure out how to implement the query conditions within the aggregate operation.

```
db.records.aggregate({
  $project: {
    RecordID: 1,
    RecordType: 1,
    Title: '$Items.Title',
    Format: '$Items.Format'
  }
})
```

**UPDATE 2:**

I have abandoned the $project solution because I would need to change the entire API to support aggregation. Also, I would need to find a solution for populate because aggregate does not support it, rather, it uses $lookup which is possible but time consuming because I would need to write the queries dynamically. I am going back to look into how to flatten the object by creating a function to iterate the array of objects recursively.

Comment: can you post a valid sample of the data you want to output as an excel file?  the blob you added has a syntaxerror

Comment: @Peter Updated the desired 'flattened' structure with valid syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a function to iterate all object in the results array and create new flattened objects recursively. The flattenObject function shown here is similar to the previous answer and I took additional inspiration from this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54896928/flattening-the-nested-object-in-javascript).

The '_id' properties are specifically excluded from being added to the flattened object, since ObjectIds are still being [returned as bson types even though I have the lean() option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42769613/mongoose-lean-returning-bson-data) set.

I still need to figure out how to sort the objects such that they are in the order given e.g. `RecordID, RecordType, Items.Title`. I believe that might be easiest to achieve by creating a separate function to iterate the flattened results, although not necessarily the most performant. Let me know if anyone has any suggestions on how to achieve the object sorting by a given order or has any improvements to the solution.

```
const apiCtrl = {};

/**
 * Async array iterator
 */
apiCtrl.asyncForEach = async (array, callback) => {
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    await callback(array[index], index, array)
  }
}

// Check if a value is an object
const isObject = (val) => {
  return typeof val == 'object' && val instanceof Object && !(val instanceof Array);
}

// Check if a value is a date object
const isDateObject = (val) => {
  return Object.prototype.toString.call(val) === '[object Date]';
}

/**
 * Iterate object properties recursively and flatten all values to top level properties
 * @param {object} obj Object to flatten
 * @param {string} prefix A string to hold the property name
 * @param {string} res A temp object to store the current iteration
 * Return a new object with all properties on the top level only
 *
 */
const flattenObject = (obj, prefix = '', res = {}) =>

  Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => {
    const k = `${prefix}${key}`

    // Skip _ids since they are returned as bson values
    if (k.indexOf('_id') === -1) {
      // Check if value is an object
      if (isObject(val) && !isDateObject(val)) {
        flattenObject(val, `${k}.`, acc)
      // Check if value is an array
      } else if (Array.isArray(val)) {
        // Iterate each array value and call function recursively
        val.map(element => {
          flattenObject(element, `${k}.`, acc);
        });
      // If value is not an object or an array
      } else if (val !== null & val !== 'undefined') {
        // Check if property has a value already
        if (res[k]) {
          // Check for duplicate values
          if (typeof res[k] === 'string' && res[k].indexOf(val) === -1) {
            // Append value with a separator character at the beginning
            res[k] += '; ' + val;
          }
        } else {
          // Set value
          res[k] = val;
        }
      }
    }

    return acc;

  }, res);

/**
 * Convert DB query results to an array of flattened objects
 * Required to build a format that is exportable to csv, xlsx, etc.
 * @param {array} results Results of DB query
 * Return a new array of objects with all properties on the top level only
 */
apiCtrl.buildExportColumns = async (results) => {

  const data = results.data;
  let exportColumns = [];

  if (data && data.length > 0) {
    try {
      // Iterate all records in results data array
      await apiCtrl.asyncForEach(data, async (record) => {

        // Convert the multi-level object to a flattened object
        const flattenedObject = flattenObject(record);
        // Push flattened object to array
        exportColumns.push(flattenedObject);

      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }

  return exportColumns;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is a solution for transforming the Mongo data on the server via a function `flattenObject` which recursively flattens nested objects and returns a 'dot-type' key for nested paths.

**Note** that the snippet below contains a function that renders and editable table to preview, however, the important part you want (download the file), should be triggered when you run the snippet and click the 'Download' button.

```js
const flattenObject = (obj, prefix = '') =>
  Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, k) => {
    const pre = prefix.length ? prefix + '.' : '';
    if (typeof obj[k] === 'object') Object.assign(acc, flattenObject(obj[k], pre + k));
    else acc[pre + k] = obj[k];
    return acc;
  }, {});

var data = [{
    RecordID: 9000,
    RecordType: "Item",
    Location: {
      _id: "5d0699326e310a6fde926a08",
      LocationName: "Example Location A"
    },
    Items: [{
        Title: "Example Title A",
        Format: {
          _id: "5d0699326e310a6fde926a01",
          FormatName: "Example Format A"
        }
      },
      {
        Title: "Example Title B",
        Format: {
          _id: "5d0699326e310a6fde926a01",
          FormatName: "Example Format B"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    RecordID: 9001,
    RecordType: "Item",
    Location: {
      _id: "5d0699326e310a6fde926a08",
      LocationName: "Example Location C"
    },
    Items: [{
      Title: "Example Title C",
      Format: {
        _id: "5d0699326e310a6fde926a01",
        FormatName: "Example Format C"
      }
    }]
  }
];

const EXCEL_MIME_TYPE = `application/vnd.ms-excel`;
const flattened = data.map(e => flattenObject(e));
const ws_default_header = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(flattened);
const ws_custom_header = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(flattened, {
  header: ['Items.Title', 'RecordID', 'RecordType', 'Location.LocationName', 'Items.Format.FormatName']
});
const def_workbook = XLSX.WorkBook = {
  Sheets: {
    'data': ws_default_header
  },
  SheetNames: ['data']
}

const custom_workbook = XLSX.WorkBook = {
  Sheets: {
    'data': ws_custom_header
  },
  SheetNames: ['data']
}

const def_excelBuffer = XLSX.write(def_workbook, {
  bookType: 'xlsx',
  type: 'array'
});

const custom_excelBuffer = XLSX.write(custom_workbook, {
  bookType: 'xlsx',
  type: 'array'
});

const def_blob = new Blob([def_excelBuffer], {
  type: EXCEL_MIME_TYPE
});

const custom_blob = new Blob([custom_excelBuffer], {
  type: EXCEL_MIME_TYPE
});

const def_button = document.getElementById('dl-def')
/* trigger browser to download file */
def_button.onclick = e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  saveAs(def_blob, `${new Date().getTime()}.xlsx`);
}

const custom_button = document.getElementById('dl-cus')
/* trigger browser to download file */
custom_button.onclick = e => {
  e.preventDefault()
  saveAs(custom_blob, `${new Date().getTime()}.xlsx`);
}

/*
  render editable table to preview (for SO convenience)
*/
const html_string_default = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_html(ws_default_header, {
  id: "data-table",
  editable: true
});

const html_string_custom = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_html(ws_custom_header, {
  id: "data-table",
  editable: true
});
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = html_string_default;
document.getElementById("container-2").innerHTML = html_string_custom;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.14.3/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>

<head>
  <title>Excel file generation from JSON</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <style>
    .xport,
    .btn {
      display: inline;
      text-align: center;
    }
    
    a {
      text-decoration: none
    }
    
    #data-table,
    #data-table th,
    #data-table td {
      border: 1px solid black
    }
  </style>
</head>
<script>
  function render(type, fn, dl) {
    var elt = document.getElementById('data-table');
    var wb = XLSX.utils.table_to_book(elt, {
      sheet: "Sheet JS"
    });
    return dl ?
      XLSX.write(wb, {
        bookType: type,
        bookSST: true,
        type: 'array'
      }) :
      XLSX.writeFile(wb, fn || ('SheetJSTableExport.' + (type || 'xlsx')));
  }
</script>
<div>Default Header</div>
<div id="container"></div>
<br/>
<div>Custom Header</div>
<div id="container-2"></div>
<br/>
<table id="xport"></table>
<button type="button" id="dl-def">Download Default Header Config</button>
<button type="button" id="dl-cus">Download Custom Header Config</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.8/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome! I will give this a try asap. Any advice on how to accept a list of column names (as an array of strings) and output the results in the given column order?

Comment: sure, by default, it uses `Object.keys` for the order.  If you give me an example array of columns I can update the example.

Comment: Here is an example, say hypothetically I want to return the results with the `Items.Title` first. The user will be setting the desired order of the columns in the UI. `['Items.Title', 'RecordID', 'RecordType', 'Location.LocationName', 'Items.Format.FormatName']`

Comment: updated my answer, however you will notice a problem due to a limitation of the flattenObject function where indexes are being flattened as well as regular string key, giving us something like `Items.0.Format._id`.  I will try to look into this later but I have to work on other stuff for the remainder of today.  good luck

Comment: Thanks so much! So far I'm getting the error message described here (because the actual data has some null values) so I think I just need to check if the value is defined before passing to Object.keys() https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29721205/how-to-resolve-typeerror-cannot-convert-undefined-or-null-to-object